# How to copy file contents from xlsm to another xlsm?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to transfer data from the master workbook to another workbook
If the transfer to destination.xlsx is successful
but if transfer to destination.xlsm is unsuccessful

this is my code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim strPath2 As String
Dim wbk As Workbook

strPath2 = "C:\destination.xlsm"

On Error Resume Next

Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strPath2)


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

 
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").Range("A1:A30").Copy
wbk.Worksheets("destination").[E15].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You entire code work properly, except this part,

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").Range("A1:A30").Copy
wbk.Worksheets("destination").[E15].PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

By using copy method, you can input destination subsequent without the need for paste special:

```
Sheet1.Range("A1:A5").Copy wbk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
```

Eventually it perform same step as your need with less code.